# Spring Boot: java.sq.SqlException: Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: spring-boot

**Here's my Spring JPA Repository I use native query like that**

[image]

And then it shows error below:

[image]

Anyone could help me, please? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: I would recommend writing five different methods for the queries and give them meaningful names. This would also make it easier for you to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your `ArrayList transStatus` is empty.

Comment: I 've logged it in console many times transStatus get from request is not null